# How to parse a json string to a List of Map in scala?

Tags: json, list, scala, dictionary, play-json

So I have a json string which looks like this:

```
{
  "time": 100,
  "velocity": 20,
  "player": [
    {"name": "player1", "strength": 5},
    {"name": "play2", "strength": 10}
  ]
}
```

Now I am trying to get convert the value of key "player" to a list of map in Scala. So I use:

```
val parsed: JsValue = Json.parse(JsString)
val players: List[Map[String, String]] = (parsed \ "player").as[List[Map[String, String]]]
```

And I got `JsResultExceptionError`  and  `JsonValidationError` .

Comment: Fhuan566, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error, is because you are trying to do an invalid cast. The Entry of `strength` is an `int`, and not a `String`. Therefore, you can fix that by calling:

```
val players: List[Map[String, String]] = (parsed \ "player").as[List[Map[String, Any]]]
```

Having said that, I prefer working with case classes representing me data.

We can first define a `Player`, and its format:

```
case class Player(name: String, strength: Int)

object Player {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Player] = Json.format[Player]
}
```

Now we can define a class for the whole json:

```
case class Entity(time: Int, velocity: Int, player: Seq[Player])

object Entity {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Entity] = Json.format[Entity]
}
```

And now we can parse it:

```
val json = Json.parse(jsonString)
json.validate[Entity] match {
  case JsSuccess(entity, _) =>
    println(entity)
  case JsError(_) => ???
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/LNsNVVa1RTKM8M6Hfs5zZA).